# Relay control using Ardiuno Mega

Tags: arduino, relay, atmega

How many relays can I drive using Ardiuno MEGA board without overloading the microcontroller?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. You're going to get downvoted and maybe put on hold unless you specify exactly what sort of relay interface you propose to use. 1 IO pint per relay? An external shift register? What? With an external shift register and power drivers you can control hundreds of relays.

Comment: yes.. One output pin per relay..I want to control 54 relays using all 54 digital pins.

Comment: Welcome to ee.se. Please read the [help] to understand how to ask good questions that get good answers. Your question seems vague, maybe too vague to give a good answer. If you specified the type of relay you needed to drive, or explained why you might not use a buffer, for example a transistor, to drive a relay which would be beyond the capability of an Arduino Mega I/O pin, or explained what you are trying to do, we might be able to give a good answer. Currently, I think the question is so vague that I would answer *every* pin which can be configured for OUTPUT could drive a relay.

Comment: I use 12VDC relays. So can I drive 54 relays using BC547 transistor connected to each digital pin which are configured as outputs ?

Comment: Add a schematic showing what you want to do, _and add additional clarifying information **in your question**_. Reading the datasheets of the components involved would also be a good idea.

Comment: I want to control 54 relays like above

Comment: This community tries to give ENGINEERING-quality answers to questions which are likely to be useful to more people than the first person who asked the question. To give a good ENGINEERING-quality answer, we need good questions. The question needs to have enough information to give an objective, fact or evidence based answer. So, for example, we need a *specification of the relay* you intend to use. In this case, we might want to know how the relays will be powered, as that might be more of a problem than buffering the arduino pins. Keep adding to your question so everyone understands easily.

Comment: Questions "how to drive relays w/ Arduino" and "how much current an Arduino/ATmega can source and sink" have been asked *ad nauseam* both here on EE.SE and on [Arduino.SE](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions).  Care to do some searching.  That is, in addition to studying the datasheet.

Comment: Based on the schematic, my answer is still every pin can drive a relay. Of course, that depends on the *specification of the relay*, and hence how much power it needs, how the relays are powered, and what you want to do. I think I might put the relay on the neutral side of the bulb. How fast do you intend to switch each bulb on and off? Are they incandescent bulbs, CFL, LEDs, or something else?

Comment: I use 230VAC/ 10A, 28VDC 10A relays and relay coil has 330ohms and I want to drive at maximum switching time of 50ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assumption:* You will use the circuit as shown, and you will use every pin on the Arduino Mega without using any external I/O expanders.

### Current consumption: 54 mA

The circuit as shown draws about (5-0.7)/4700 mA, roughly 1 mA from the Arduino when enabled. The Arduino Mega has 54 pins that can be configured as an output.

### Limit: 200 mA

The [Arduino Mega](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega) uses an [ATmega1280](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATMEGA1280.aspx) MCU. The total current limit for this device is 200 mA.

In summary, the answer is **54**, or **all of them**.

Comment: Ohh... Is 1mA enough to bias BC547 ?? and also the chip is Atmega2560

Comment: @channa That question does not make much sense, you're not biasing the transistor, you're turning it on. And the answer is longer than can fit in a comment. If you have another question, I suggest that you post it as a question, or even better, do some research first so your question will not be downvoted.

Comment: Can I use D313 or D400 instead of BC547 ?

Comment: @channa Probably. It depends on the relay.

Comment: I use 230VAC/ 10A, 28VDC 10A relays and relay coil has 330ohms

Comment: @channa There are a lot of pages that teaches how to drive a relay, and a StackExchange comment is not enough to give a simple answer to that. As I wrote above, I suggest you start a new question because it is a new subject.